# Xcode 11.0 has entitlements that require signing with a development certificate. Enable development signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode Version 11.0:

I recently upgraded to Xcode Version 11.0.

And received the following error:

> "Application has entitlements that require signing with a development certificate. Enable development signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor."

Where do I enable Signing?  There isn't anything available form the "General" tab any more.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode Version 11.0:

I recently upgraded to Xcode Version 11.0.

Looks like Apple moved Signing to a new tab from the General tab.

1. Navigate to the application
2. Select "Signing & Capabilities"
3. Click "Enable Development Signing"

[image: Image showing issue resolution steps]

Comment: Any idea how to disable Development Signing? I'm getting this message and can't turn it off.